# I need to open a pdf as it get saved, token system in place to hide the url, the pdf opens from regular pages but not in the function

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

I'm using codeigniter and CRSF protection is on.

I'm stuck with this function that is supposed to:

-Save pdf data from the editor (is in a modal)
-Open it directly after saving and closing the modal

this is the controller function used to open pdf from the db:

```
public function print()
{
    $data = array();

    // Retrieve the token from POST data.
    $token = $this->input->post('token');

    // Retrieve the report ID using the token.
    $report_access = $this->report_model->get_report_access_by_token($token);

    // Check if the token is valid and not expired.
    if (!$report_access || new DateTime() > new DateTime($report_access->expires_at)) {
        show_error("Report not found or Link expired"); 
        return; // Stop further execution of the code.
    }

    $mrid = $report_access->report_id; // Use the report ID from the access token.

    // Proceed with the rest of the function using $mrid...
    $data['financial'] = $this->report_model->single_view($mrid);
    if (empty($data['financial'])) {
        show_error("Report not found"); // No report found.
        return;
    }

    // Retrieve related data based on the report.
...

    // Check if preview is requested.
    if ($this->input->get('p') == 1)
    {
        echo $this->load->view('dashboard/report/report_print', $data); 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('dashboard/report/report_print', $data);

        // Get output html and generate the PDF as before.
        $html = $this->output->get_output();
        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $this->dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $this->dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        $this->dompdf->render();

        $path = FCPATH . './assets/attachments/broucher/b-' . $mrid . ".pdf";
        $output = $this->dompdf->output();
        file_put_contents($path, $output);

        // Stream the PDF to the browser.
        $this->dompdf->stream("report-" . date("ymdhis") . ".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
    }
}
```

this is the view:

```
function saveReport() {
    var reportContent = tinymce.get('ReportEditor').getContent();
    var userId = $('#userId').val();
    var appointmentId = $('#appointmentId').val();
    var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');

    $.ajax({
        
        url: '<?php echo base_url('dashboard/home/save_report/'); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            report: reportContent,
            user_id: userId,
            appointment_id: appointmentId,
            user2_id: user2Id,
            date: currentDate,
            draft: 0,
            [csrfName]: csrfHash
        },
        success: function(response) {
                console.log('AJAX Success called');

            console.log(response); // Check the response
            var token = response.token;
            if (token) {
                // Update the CSRF token with the new one from the response
                csrfHash = response.new_csrf_hash;


                // Dynamically create a form and submit it to open the PDF
                var form = $('<form>', {
                    'action': '<?php echo base_url("dashboard/report/report/print"); ?>',
                    'target': '_blank',
                    'method': 'post',
                    'style': 'display: none;'
                });

                // Append the token and CSRF fields to the form
                form.append($('<input>', {
                    'name': 'token',
                    'value': token,
                    'type': 'hidden'
                }));
                form.append($('<input>', {
                    'name': csrfName,
                    'value': csrfHash,
                    'type': 'hidden'
                }));

                $('body').append(form);
                    console.log('Form appended:', form);

console.log('Submitting form:', form);
form.submit();
console.log('Form submitted');
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

It saves the report correctly but doesn't open the pdf after.

In the console i see:

AJAX Success called
home:918 {"status":"success","reportId":17623,"token":"b852d1c7bfeb2337669910226a02a697a154c90e366999ae51ab823d011fcebf","new_csrf_hash":"1be13552876f33c79f2061ec9a21962b"}

and in network tab the print function is not getting called.

I have this buttons generated on the same page and they work correctly opening the pdf:

```
            // Instead of an 'a' tag, create a form for the action to keep the token hidden
            $fetch_data['actions'] = form_open('dashboard/report/report/print', ['target' => '_blank']) .
                                     form_hidden('token', $token) .
                                     form_submit('submit', 'Open', 'class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"') .
                                     form_close();
```

Do you have any suggestion on what is going on?

popup is allowed on the page and there are no errors visible.

I've tried to simulate a human click but still same result. I think it should work normally with this form approach since it works for the buttons on the same page not sure what i'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

In JS

```
function saveReport() {
    var reportContent = tinymce.get('ReportEditor').getContent();
    var userId = $('#userId').val();
    var appointmentId = $('#appointmentId').val();
    var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url('dashboard/home/save_report/'); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            report: reportContent,
            user_id: userId,
            appointment_id: appointmentId,
            user2_id: user2Id,
            date: currentDate,
            draft: 0,
            [csrfName]: csrfHash
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('AJAX Success called');
            console.log(response); // Check the response

            if (response.status === 'success' && response.token && response.new_csrf_hash) {
                // Update the CSRF token with the new one from the response
                csrfHash = response.new_csrf_hash;

                // Dynamically create a form and submit it to open the PDF
                var form = $('<form>', {
                    'action': '<?php echo base_url("dashboard/report/report/print"); ?>',
                    'target': '_blank',
                    'method': 'post',
                    'style': 'display: none;'
                });

                // Append the token and CSRF fields to the form
                form.append($('<input>', {
                    'name': 'token',
                    'value': response.token,
                    'type': 'hidden'
                }));
                form.append($('<input>', {
                    'name': csrfName,
                    'value': csrfHash,
                    'type': 'hidden'
                }));

                $('body').append(form);
                console.log('Form appended:', form);

                console.log('Submitting form:', form);
                form.submit();
                console.log('Form submitted');
            } else {
                console.error('Invalid response:', response);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error('AJAX Error:', error);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller function

```
public function print()
{
    $data = array();

    // Retrieve the token from POST data.
    $token = $this->input->post('token');
    $report_access = $this->report_model->get_report_access_by_token($token);

    // Check if the token is valid and not expired.
    if (!$report_access || new DateTime() > new DateTime($report_access->expires_at)) {
        show_error("Report not found or Link expired"); 
        return; // Stop further execution of the code.
    }

    $mrid = $report_access->report_id; // Use the report ID from the access token.

    // Add debugging statements
    log_message('debug', 'Report ID from access token: ' . $mrid);

    // Proceed with the rest of the function using $mrid...
    $data['financial'] = $this->report_model->single_view($mrid);
    if (empty($data['financial'])) {
        show_error("Report not found"); // No report found.
        return;
    }

    // Your existing code...

    // Check if preview is requested.
    if ($this->input->get('p') == 1)
    {
        echo $this->load->view('dashboard/report/report_print', $data); 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('dashboard/report/report_print', $data);

        // Your existing code...
    }
}
```